# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getServletMapping()

Tags: jsp

I'd like to ask a question about  error. whenever I execute program I got this error. Below codes is just for testing connection between two pages.
Both of two files are in the same directory, which is within WebContent. I'm using eclipse and tomcat 9. If I use <%@ include file=""....>, it works well. However, jsp:include ,jsp:forward  don't work. Please help me

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest.getServletMapping()Ljavax/servlet/http/ServletMapping;

---

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="another2.jsp" flush="true"></jsp:include> 
</body>
</html>
```

---

another2.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
    pageEncoding="UTF-8" import="java.util.*"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
    <p>helllllllloooooooooo</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you shipping java ee jars in your application archive?

Comment: I'm not sure about that... where can I check java ee jars?

Comment: Please make sure you have correct version of servlet.jar and J2EE.jar